# Calculate age in months - optimize date transformations in pandas

Tags: pandas, datetime

I am trying a very simple thing - to calculate age in months between two columns and save it to a new column

```
df['AGE'] = (df.apply(lambda x: (x['DAX'].year - int(x['BIRTH_DATE'][:4])) * 12 +
                                     x['DAX'].month - int(x['BIRTH_DATE'][5:7])
                                     if x['BIRTH_DATE'] is not None
                                         and int(x['BIRTH_DATE'][:4]) > 1900
                                     else -1                 # data quality
                          , axis=1).astype(np.int8))
```

I am doing this while loading a pretty big 2Gb csv file. DAX is parsed directly in the reader while BIRTH_DATE is left as string.

And this simple calculation bumps up the load time by a factor of x10. Is there any smarter way to calculate age in months on big data frames?

Here is a sample of data:

```
DAX         BIRTH_DATE    
2015-01-01  1931-12-03  
2015-01-01  1991-04-19
2015-01-01  1992-10-11
2015-01-01  1982-05-20
2015-01-01  1987-12-20
2015-01-01  1976-07-30
2015-01-01  1951-05-11
2015-01-01  1993-05-06
2015-01-01  1989-02-27
```

I am trying to get another column 'AGE' as number of months since birthday.

Comment: added to the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first convert `BIRTH_DATE` to `datetime` dtype:

```
In [257]: df['BIRTH_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['BIRTH_DATE'], errors='coerce')
```

check:

```
In [258]: df.dtypes
Out[258]:
DAX           datetime64[ns]
BIRTH_DATE    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

now we can do this simple math:

```
In [259]: df['AGE'] = df.DAX.dt.year*12 + df.DAX.dt.month - \
                      (df.BIRTH_DATE.dt.year*12 + df.BIRTH_DATE.dt.month)

In [260]: df
Out[260]:
         DAX BIRTH_DATE  AGE
0 2015-01-01 1931-12-03  997
1 2015-01-01 1991-04-19  285
2 2015-01-01 1992-10-11  267
3 2015-01-01 1982-05-20  392
4 2015-01-01 1987-12-20  325
5 2015-01-01 1976-07-30  462
6 2015-01-01 1951-05-11  764
7 2015-01-01 1993-05-06  260
8 2015-01-01 1989-02-27  311
```

Comment: Looks like a speed-up of factor 5x. However I get strange results for (among others)

DAX, BIRTH_DATE, AGE

2015-01-01,1980-09-15,-100

there should not be any negative result

Comment: The guilty one was astype(np.int8). This is not age in years but in months and I had a type overflow

Comment: @snovik, why do you need `.astype()` at all? Didn't my solution work as it is?

Answer (score 0):

As you have not provided any sample data I'm not completely sure what format your data is in. Something like this should work though and be considerably faster than using `apply()`:

```
df['AGE'] = (df.DAX - df.BIRTH_DATE.astype('datetime64[ns]')).dt.days / 30
```

Again without the data I'm not sure what you're data quality steps needs to do, but it will probably be fixed after the above line like so:

```
df.loc[df['AGE'].isnull(), 'AGE'] = -1
```

Comment: added a sample though there is nothing special in it. The null check should be in-line because otherwise the lambda in the current form will throw